# Athena on S3 using secrets key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have got a key and secrets key for an external S3 bucket full of .gz files.
I need to analyze this data using Athena.
Is there an option to connect Athena to the S3 bucket using a key and secret key? if so, how to do it?

I know how to connect S3 when I get a console connection but not when I've only a key and secret key.

Comment: Are you wanting to use Amazon Athena via the AWS console, or will you be accessing it via an SQL Client (which one)? The simple answer is that an Access Key + Secret Key cannot be used for console access -- but you can ask them for a Username + Password if that is what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more comlicated than answering with a single answer.

As it was mentioned already, you cannot have access to the console with only the secret key. You can use those credential for programatic access for example from your CLI.

What you might want to try is to use the AWS CLI tool. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/athena/start-query-execution.html

`aws athena start-query-execution <query>`

Comment: Thanks, where can I find a python code or tutorial that makes a simple query on external S3 using a key and secret key for connection?

Comment: you can find the boto3 documentation here https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.start_query_execution